# Multidimensional NSMutableArray to Multi column UiTableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

everyone I am struggling with this problem for too long and I lost my patience.

All I need is to convert this NSMutableArray to

```
array: (
        (
        3,
        Name1
    ),
        (
        4,
        Name2
    ),
        (
        5,
        Name3
    )
)
```

to UITableView that will look like that

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zidfw8w4kegfcya/Screenshot%202015-05-24%2016.09.38.png?dl=0

Is it realy so hard? Everyone is talking about custom cells but i could not find any working example...

If it would be possible to add detailText so it could look like that

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5sskjxma4zxw58/Screenshot%202015-05-24%2016.09.17.png?dl=0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this example: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

But I think you should convert this array of arrays in an array of dictionaries, it would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks I followed it step by step and it works https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqfu8kwjyfnrico/Screenshot%202015-05-24%2017.48.48.png?dl=0